# Which lightsaber form(s) did General Grievous know?

Tags: star-wars

In Episode III, when Grievous is about to face off against Obi-Wan Kenobi he says

> I've been trained in your Jedi Arts by Count Dooku.

Which lightsaber form(s) was he trained in, if any?

Is this mentioned in one of the movie novelizations or anywhere else?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In [Star Wars: Labyrinth of Evil](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Labyrinth_of_Evil) (which is now part of the [Legends Canon](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Legends)), Count Dooku teaches Grievous how to fight with lightsabers. Dooku's specialty is [Form 2: Makashi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Form_II:_Makashi), but he has a working knowledge of all seven forms.

Grievous was trained in all seven as well.

Per [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Grievous)

> Dooku, impressed with the general's performance at Geonosis, trained Grievous in the art of lightsaber combat, which Grievous took to at a rapid pace.
>
> Learning all the seven classic forms of Jedi arts—including the rarely seen Makashi and Juyo — Grievous quickly surpassed all the other apprentices of Dooku in terms of individual combat.

Answer (score 6):

Wookieepedia cites the Legends novel [*Labyrinth of Evil*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Labyrinth_of_Evil) in claiming that [Grievous knew all seven lightsaber forms](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Grievous#The_Clone_Wars). Wookieepedia also mentions that the [novelization for *Revenge of the Sith*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_%28novel%29) heavily references *Labyrinth of Evil* so presumably the claim in *Labyrinth of Evil* that Grievous knew all seven forms would be supported by the *Revenge of the Sith* novelization even if not directly mentioned.